# How does Angular components re render when data is updated?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-dependency-injection

I would like to understand how an Angular component re-render to display the new information whenever there is a change in the underlying data. (eg. push/delete)

I have the following component that uses a data service to get the data. When the component is first initialised, the constructor is executed and existing data is retrieved if any.

**Table.component.ts**

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  table : Task[]
  dropdowns = ["green", "yellow", "red"]
  taskName : string
  taskStatus : string
  @ViewChild('form') form: NgForm

  
  constructor(private tableService : TableService) {
    // if I comment the line below my table does not get updated when submitTask() is run.
    this.table = tableService.getData();
  }
 
  submitTask() {
    const taskName : string = this.form.form.value.taskName
    const taskStatus : string = this.form.form.value.taskStatus
    const task: Task = {item: taskName, status: taskStatus}
    this.tableService.addData(task)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

**Table.service.ts**

```
export class TableService {
  tableData : Task[] = []

  constructor() { }

  addData(task : Task) {
    this.tableData.push(task)
  }

  getData() : Task[] {
    return this.tableData
  }


}
```

the `submitTask()` function of the component uses the `tableService` to update the `table` data source. Whenever `submitTask()` is called, it seems that the `this.table` array suddenly gets updated as well. Is the constructor of the `TableComponent` called again ? I am not sure of the angular workflow for handling data changes.

Comment: I think this is a useful article: [Angular change detection](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't share the service code with us but likely your `getData()` is just returning the array *reference* stored in the service.

This means that the component `table` is then assigned this reference and thus any change in the array in the service is reflected in the component because they basically are pointing to the same data.

> Is the constructor of the TableComponent called again ?

No.

Comment: I have added the tableService method. You are right in that it is just returning the array. Is the angular component re-rendering in that case ? In `ReactJS` any state variable change will cause the component to re-render. Because I don't have the `@Input()` decorator, I don't understand why the component will re-render it's view.

Comment: I recommend reading about change detection, there are different situations, long to explain in one comment.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ChangeDetectorRef` for refreshing the data.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

//...

table: Task[];

constructor(private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef, 
            private tableService : TableService) { }

//...

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.refresh();
}

refresh() {      
   this.tableService.getData().subscribe((data: Task[]) => {
   this.table = data;
   this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
  }
}
```